# Crop image in diagonal square

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following image in a `Mat`:

[image: initital Mat]

The black rectangle is created using the class `rotatedRect`. How can I have the following result?

[image: final Mat]

**EDIT:**

I manage to do it with the following code:

> cv::Mat src, dst; float angle, x, y;
>
> cv::Mat imgRotated = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(Point(50,50), angle,
>   1.0); cv::warpAffine(src, dst, imgRotated, Size(x,y));
>
> imshow("image", dst);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cv::warpAffine()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html) together with [`cv::getRotationMatrix2D()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warp#getrotationmatrix2d).
There is an example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html).

Comment: In my destination Mat I get the image rotated, yet I only see the corner of it, Do you know how can I get the center of the image?

Comment: @lulas: Though I don't completely understand, your `dst` origin is probably off. Look into the `cv::getRotationMatrix2D()` docs to see how to change that. Alternatively, post another question with the code and result images and link it here. I'll take a look.